# Amazon Cloudfront always server from the same edge location

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I setup a basic test page which displays the same image from three sources: origin server, s3 server and cloudfront server: http://ocp.mofarchive.com/index.html

Then I run tests using webpagetest.org from various locations. Unfortunately image that should be hosted in closest edge server is donwloaded from Amazon's Seattle server all the time.

I'm seeing the correct image and test result says that CDN usage is OK so I couldn't figure out how I can make the edge locations work.

Comment: Is there something new on this topic?
We have the same problem. All the requests are handled by the american datacenter. I would expect that files requested by a european visitor would be delivered from london or frankfurt. Just posted on amazon forum. Maybe we get infos from the support team.
Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely explain here:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=195458&#195458

In short, the online tools are probably using the geoip lookup and relying on the whois information (which is showing where the HQ of the company is, rather than the physical location of where the IPs are being used).

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem. I was using wget to download from my cloudfront distribution and then used an ip lookup on the ip address from the response.  The first ip lookup site I used always said the ip address was from Seattle.  Echoing the above answer, I found some different ip lookup sites that listed the actual physical location of the download.

- http://www.ip2location.com/demo
- https://www.iplocation.net/

The https://www.iplocation.net/ site shows results from several different ip lookup services.  Here you can see some say the ip address is from Amazon HQ while others show the actual edge location being used.